# On/Off control of step-up DC to DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I simply want to on/off control Vout of "step-up DC to DC converter(NCP1402)" ; toggling chip's CE pin by AVR GPIO, but Vout does not go 0V when CE pin set to Low(<0.3V = disabled).

The datasheet says [When voltage at pin CE is less than 0.3 V, the chip is disabled, which means IC is shutdown.] and "shutdown" means stop output Vout in my understanding...does this wrong?

The shematic I am using is [NCP1402 Evaluation Board Schematic] showed in the datasheet, and CE pin directly connected to AVR GPIO pin in my shematic.

[NCP1402]
http://www.onsemi.jp/pub/Collateral/NCP1402-D.PDF

Comment: As Dave says. One solution is to use a two winding inductor. The output winding connects to ground so there is never any Vin DC component present. The inductor can be 1:1 and you MAY be able to use a 1:1 ferrite bead/choke. Efficincy will be lower as now all energy is magnetically transferred whereas before Vin formed part of Vout (as you are finding).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on the schematic, with this type of boost converter, there is a direct path from input to output through the inductor and the diode. Even if you remove the IC from the circuit altogether, this path still exists.

If you want the output voltage to go to zero, you'll have to switch the input voltage separately, e.g., using a P-channel MOSFET. The enable pin of the IC isn't going to do it for you.